# start service from activity or find out when service work is finished in activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, service

I have seen other question they asked how to start activity from service but methods they used doesn't work in android 10. so i'm trying to start another activity when the thing i'm doing in my service is done
if any one know how please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found way by my self you can set it in the alarm manager to open it after your works done. thanks to one of the gods of android amin haery ny teacher.